# is it possible to use near beer as my wort and add brewers yeast to have beer with %5-6 ABV?

Tags: beer

Good day to everyone in here! This is my first post and I'm a newbie in here , and I would like to ask you guys if I can use non alcoholic beer ( near beer) as my wort + brewer yeast ( not bread yeast) to get %5-6 ABV ? The reason is because in where I'm living its almost impossible to get malt extract and the only barely malt extract I found in one market it costs 50$ per 1 LBs which is very expensive , that's why I'm wondering if I can use the near beer as a substitute, thanks a lot and best regards!

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to ferment in near beer. It is not a sweet malty beverage normally.  Adding yeast to it won't give you anymore alcohol.

You could add sugar or some other malt beverage (e.g. [Malta-Goya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malta_(soft_drink))) and ferment that but, this isn't going to generate a beer in the sense that you are thinking.

Perhaps wine or mead making is better suited to your area as those starting materials are often a bit more universal.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try making "syntha-beer". Alcohol and carbon dioxide come from fermenting sugars (like glucose or sucrose) . Sugars are usually relatively easy to obtain. So fermenting a solution of sugar with yeast will yeild a base fizzy alcoholic brew. If you want to make it more "malty" try adding "ovalteen" malt drink powder. If you want to make it "thicker" with more turbidity then use maltodextrin (commonly available as a body building additive).

Next comes flavouring and colouring which usually comes from hops and some aspect of roast grain. Presuming one can obtain hops, it is simplest to boil them in water to make "hop tea" and strain that into the brew. The next thing is to find some roast grain like a crystal, chocolate or roast malt. Dark roast barley is sometimes sold as an alternative to decaf coffee. If all else fails use raw barley grains or raw wheat grains and roast them on a tray in an oven until they turn brown to the desired degree. Crack/crush the roast grain, steep in boiled water for (say) 30 mins and strain the brown liquid into your fermentation bin with the sugars, maltodextrin and hop tea.

It might not be the same as a pint of "Courage Best" but in a hot country far from the homebrew shop - served cold and fizzy it can taste like nectar - and gives a cracking hangover!

Comment: Is "syntha-beer" a reference from something?  Fascinating advise, I almost want to try it, except the cracking hangover.  Did you come up with this recipe or speak from experience?  Highly creative nonetheless, a step up from pruno.

Comment: It was developed for/with a friend who lived in "a hot country with no home brew shops". He looked in the local stores for what he could get and the only thing he had to "import" were the hops. The name "syntha beer" is mine after a project I had trying to make a clone of "Bud-Lite" using only glucose, maltodextrin, hop essence and caramel/colouring. I am aghast to say the results were unnervingly accurate! I have a particular fascination for brewing "beer" from improbable ingredients in unheard of locations.  ...but I brew the real stuff too. 12 pints of that can give me a hangover as well!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question. Absolutely. If you live somewhere where there is no beer available, but there is a quality near beer such as Holsten or Becks, you can make a quality beer.

Recipe:
5 gallon plastic water jug,
16 liters of holsten(48 x 355ml)
1-1.5 kg of light brown sugar,
1 pack of Nottingham or Windsor yeast,
Stopper at the top of jug to allow fermentation,
Wait 1-2 weeks,
Rack or transfer from original jug to secondary clean jug leaving yeast residue behind.
Add 1cup white sugar and mix well to prime and restore carbonation,
Bottle in ikea resealable bottles,
Wait 3 weeks,
Fantastic beer - better than cheap store bought beer because of the natural carbonation and full bodied flavors that comes from Holsten which starts out as a quality regular beer but the alcohol is removed. and the cost is less than a buck a beer.
My experience is 12 years of approx. 1500 to 2000 beers/year